# Is there any moodle API to get quiz data?

Tags: moodle-api, moodle-mobile

I have already check the mod/quiz/db/services.php , but not able to find any api for the same.

Note : Quiz data like questions, answers details.

Comment: Hi, please check the below moodle doc .. 

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Question_API

hope this will help

Comment: I have already checked the same. but not able to get the api for the same. Please help

Answer (score 5):

Yes, if you are using moodle webservices, you can use `mod_quiz_get_attempt_data` for get questions data. You can use a lot of other functions by [this link](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Quiz_support_in_the_Mobile_app).

Bellow is an example of usage:

```
http://yourwebsite.com/moodle/webservice/rest/server.php?moodlewsrestformat=json&wstoken=YOUR_TOKEN&wsfunction=mod_quiz_get_attempt_data&attemptid=1&page=0
```

> You have to replace *attemptid*, *wstoken* and *page*. I hope this helps

If you don't know how to enable webservices in moodle platform, you just need to go [this link](https://docs.moodle.org/33/en/Using_web_services).

Comment: any tip for processing the response of `mod_quiz_get_attempt_data`? it seems all questions are returned inside html field on questions object.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, its been a long while since I've messed with moodle,  and back then this was one of my main concerns, to build my own layout. I don't think there's an easy way to do it as we speak. They really just return HTML, and I think it's kinda cool because imagine the headache it would be to reimplement all kinds of questions. But it is possible for you to try inject your own CSS within the response, I think it would be the way to go.